# Mutable BasicDynaBean Map

Tags: java

As i mentioned at the mail subject, i am having problem with not mutable map inside BasicDynaBean.
As far as i know, it is the default behaviour of this map.
What i would like to do is, simply retrieve the resultset from db which will create a list including DynaBeans.
For viewing the database table, everything works fine, the problem occurs when i try to edit it and i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException
    at javax.el.MapELResolver.setValue(MapELResolver.java:267)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.setValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:281)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.setValue(AstValue.java:201)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
    ... 50 more
```

I assume, this is because of the map inside dyna bean is not mutable.
I think one option is to change the default behaviour of the map by editing the source code of BeanUtils library.
On the other hand, i think the implementors of this library must have thought this functionality somehow...
Below is the code snippet that i use for retrieving the result set as DynaBeans.

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM test.a";

    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    RowSetDynaClass rsdc = new RowSetDynaClass(rs);

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    dynaObjectList= rsdc.getRows();
```

I tried to use LazyDynaMap as well, editing the table worked fine but the
Map didnt allow me to put multiple data since the key is not unique for other datasets.
Because the key is the property name.

I would be really appreciated if you suggest me hints.
Thanks in advance.
I am really looking forward to see the answers if possible.
Best regards.
Ercan CANLIER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, BasicDynaBean has mutable map for the DynaBeans. I created another map which is immutable by LazyDynaMap and solved the problem. Hope this helps for someone else.

```
setDecoratedDynaObjectList(rsdc.getRows());
    Iterator<DynaBean> it=decoratedDynaObjectList.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        BasicDynaBean dynaBean = (BasicDynaBean) it.next();
        Map<String,Object> modifiableMap=new DynaBeanPropertyMapDecorator(dynaBean, false);
        DynaBean mutableDynaBean=new LazyDynaMap(modifiableMap);
        modifiableDynaObjectList.add(mutableDynaBean);
    }
```